# Render with other HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is a code basic in react

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

My problem is that I have multiple addresses building components off. That is

```
+ index.html
+ component
    + hello.html
    + world.html
```

And I need you react charge for those templates. It will be possible to do something like this?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: "component/hello.html"
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: that defeats the pattern of reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Create React components rather than HTML files.

```
+ index.html
+ component
  + hello.jsx
  + world.jsx
```

For instance `component/hello.jsx` would look like this:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});
```

Then just require the components with a module bundler like webpack or browserify.

```
var Hello = require('./component/hello');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: In what way are they dynamic?

Comment: The component is not dynamic, in the html.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following you at all. Maybe it would be helpful to include one of the HTML files in your question so that I can see?